# Where In Visual Studio do I change the color of the edit field in the watch window?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How do I change the color of and edit field inside a watch box in Visual Studio 2013? I'm getting yellow over white when using the dark theme. Tried to switch to the light theme, and still get the yellow over white.

I want to either change the text color or the background color to something legible.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was an Extension called TextHighlighterExtension.

For those who have the same problem. 
Go to 
Tools -> Options -> Text Highligher

Choose TXT extensions and change the NavahoWhite to RoyalBlue or any other color that is legible in both white and dark background.

Answer (score 0):

Tools - Options - Environment - Fonts And Colors
then in the right pane, find the "show setting for" item, and select "watch window",